# AWS CodeBuild Batch configuration not passing environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, sbt, aws-codebuild, cicd

I am trying to use the CodeBuild Batch configuration feature to trigger 2 different build from the same repository.
For the 2 build commands, only some parameters differ which I am trying to manage through environment variables, below is the `buildSpec` file.

```
version: 0.2
batch:
  fast-fail: true
  build-list:
    - identifier: build1
      buildspec: buildspec1.yml
      env:
        variables:
          BUILD_ID:  build1ID
          privileged-mode: true
          PROJECT: Projectvalue
      ignore-failure: false
    - identifier: evaluator-build
      buildspec: buildspecs2.yml
      env:
        variables:
          BUILD_ID: build2ID
          PROJECT: ProjectValueTwo
      ignore-failure: false

phases:
  build:
    commands:
    - echo Build started on `date`
    - sbt clean
    - sbt 'project $PROJECT' 'compile'
```

Here `Project` is one of the variables I am trying to pass between the 2 builds, but the actual value is not being passed. I tried echoing the value for it but comes out as blank.

What could be wrong here? Also, is the batch config feature use correct here?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. The `batch` configuration block is only used in **batch** builds, not in **single** builds.

You can run batch builds either using 'build with overrides' or configured via a webhook then selecting **batch** rather than **single**. Once I switched to this then it worked as expected for me with environment variables being inserted.

Please note you need to add a 'batch configuration' for your CodeBuild project before this will work:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/create-project-console.html#create-project-console-batch-config

If you don't have a batch configuration then a webhook-triggered build seems to silently fail but you do get an error if you try to run a batch build from 'build with overrides'.